# Where do I have to put my Django middlewares for the cache?

Tags: django, caching, middleware

I tried to add caching to my Django project, so I added the cache middleware as stated (for what I've understood) in the official docs and obtained this:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
]
```

But this is breaking my authentication system: in other pages I fetch different querysets for different auth levels, but if I add those middlewares the same page is shown to all the users.
How can I implement caching in my project and still be able to provide pages different querysets for different users?

Here is my function from `views.py`:

```
class ProgettoListView(generic.ListView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    model = Progetto
    template_name = 'main/list/progetto_list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProgettoListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['ore'] = []
        for progetto in Progetto.objects.all():
            ore_lavoro = Task.objects.filter(progetto=progetto).aggregate(sum_all=Sum('durata')).get('sum_all')
            if ore_lavoro is None:
                ore_lavoro = datetime.timedelta(0)
            context['ore'].append({'nome': progetto.nome, 'ore_lavorate': ore_lavoro,
                                   'percentuale': int(ore_lavoro / progetto.tempo_stimato * 100)})
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.user.is_amm:
            return self.model.objects.all()
        return self.model.objects.filter(auts=self.request.user)
```

with `is_amm` being just a boolan field, `auts` being a list of users.

Here is the line from `urls.py`:

```
    path('pm/lista/progetti', login_required(views.ProgettoListView.as_view()), name='lista-progetti'),
```

The problem I encounter is that a user with is_amm set to true should see all the projects in database when visiting the list page, but this is not happening. For example, if i make a new project with that user he won't be able to see it in the listview, although being able to access it through direct URL.

Comment: How are you using those querysets? Add some code to show what the problem is and highlight what the problem you see is.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the problem you're encountering is that views are being cached with the wrong permissions. My guess is that you've added the `cache_page` decorator to views by itself. The problem with that approach is that it's going to cache the response for any request to that specific URL. To allow a URL to have multiple cached responses there are at least two options.

1. Create a new decorator similar to (or wrap) `cache_page` so that the decorator will check the user's permissions, then fetch the relevant cached response.
2. Don't use `cache_page` and manage the caching manually via the [low-level api](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/cache/#the-low-level-cache-api).

Personally I'd opt for #2 as it'll be a bit clearer, but I'd imagine #1 has the possibility of being more concise.